# ASP.NET Sitemap .ResourceKey property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using standard ASP.NET and a Web.sitemap file which describes the navigation structure of the site.
Now, I want to use my resourceKey attribute as a page identifier in my code, so I can perform eg. authorization checks and similar.

Problem is it's always null, for example when retrieving SiteMap.CurrentNode.ResourceKey

I have tried to set enableLocalization="true" in the Web.sitemap, and <siteMap enable="true" /> in Web.config but that doesn't help.

Any advice?

Thanks, Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution myself: It's necessary to create a .resx file for the sitemap in App_GlobalResources before one can access the resource keys.

IMO this is not 100% logical, but ResourceKeys are not supposed to be used for other things than localizing, once could argue.

Comment: but the Resource key is the property of siteampnode, It should be accessble without adding .resx file??

Comment: It is accessible, but apparently you cannot read the value from the .Sitemap file unless you have a resource file too